# Java servlet and IO: Create a file without saving to disk and sending it to the user

Tags: java, servlets, io, response, outputstream

I`m hoping can help me out with a file creation/response question.
I know how to create and save a file. I know how to send that file back to the user via a ServletOutputStream.

But what I need is to create a file, without saving it on the disk, and then send that file via the ServletOutputStream.

The code above explains the parts that I have. Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
// This Creates a file
//
String   text = "These days run away like horses over the hill";
File     file = new File("MyFile.txt");
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer.write(text);
writer.close();

// Missing link goes here
//

// This sends file to browser
//
InputStream inputStream = null;
inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\MyFile.txt");

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int bytesRead;
while (  (bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
   baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

response.setContentType("text/html");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Invoice.txt");

byte[] outBuf = baos.toByteArray();
stream = response.getOutputStream();
stream.write(outBuf);
```

Comment: Rather than saving the data to a file and then reading the file and transferring the bytes, just cut out the middle man - send the bytes to the client without saving them to a file first.

Comment: Thanks Deco. I think my question wasn't well asked. Your comment is exactly what I wanted to do but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to save off a file, just use a ByteArray stream, try something like this:

`inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());`

Or, even simpler, just do:

`stream.write(text.getBytes());`

As [cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao) suggests, use `text.getBytes("UTF-8")` or something similar to specify a charset other than the system default. The list of available charsets is available in the API docs for [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/spi/package-summary.html).

Comment: Specifying an encoding, of course...  `text.getBytes("UTF-8")`, for example.