# Servlet return corrupted '.pdf' file

Tags: java, servlets, stream

Maybe I don't understand the streams but I have servlet like this:

```
String filename  = "test.pdf";          
String Str1 = new String("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos omnes mandamus in, modus voluptua ei mel. Nec et illud facete maluisset, ");
byte[] Str2 = Str1.getBytes();

InputStream inputStream = null;
inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Str2);

byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int bytesRead;
while (  (bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
   baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

But when I try to open the file after save there's error:

[image]

I checked and the baos have string "Lorem ipsum". What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just send a `string` as `PDF` and expect it to be in `PDF` format. This is same as saving a `text` file with the extension `pdf`.

You will have to use a library Like [`Apache PDFBox`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to convert your string to `PDF` format. Take a look at their documentation for an [example](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597646/java-servlet-and-io-create-a-file-without-saving-to-disk-and-sending-it-to-the What about this ?

Comment: @Adamo That example shows sending a simple text file. A text file just contains text, whereas PDF is a complex format that includes metadata such as formatting, fonts and more. So you won't be able to use that example for PDF as it is.

Comment: Understand. Thank's for that :D I accept your anserw later ;)

Comment: @Adamo I recommend to look at the HelloWorld.java example of PDFBox. You can use that, you only need to change that save() is done to your outputstream.