# Create and edit a File object in java without physically writing to hard disc

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create and edit a text file object in java. But once I execute the code, it is physically writing the file in root folder from which the program being executed. How can I do the same without physically writing the text file to hard disc?

```
File file = new File("tempFile.txt"); // Now the file is not created physically
writeIntoFile(file, listOfString); // After this, the file is created in disc
    
private static void writeIntoFile(File file, List<String> contents) {
    Writer output;
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getPath(), true));
        for (String content : contents) {
            output.append(content);
            output.append("\r\n");
    }
    output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe class [java.io.StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringWriter.html) is appropriate?

Comment: I have found a similar question in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597646/java-servlet-and-io-create-a-file-without-saving-to-disk-and-sending-it-to-the) check this out

Comment: @User_1940878 no problem. Just took a thorough google search hahah.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gerome Tahud. The below code did the trick!

```
private static byte[] writeIntoFile(List<String> contents) {
        try {
            if (null != contents && contents.size() > 0) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                for (String content : contents) {
                    content = content + "\r\n";
                    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                return baos.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```